# "cannot be resolved to type" error when instantiating a class

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, javasound

I've created a class named "soundStuff.java"

```java
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class soundStuff {
    void playSounds(String Location) {
        try {
            File soundPath = new File(Location);
            
            if(soundPath.exists()) {
                AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundPath);
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.start();
            }
            
            else {
                System.out.println("Can't find file");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

whenever I try to instantiate it in my Game.java function

```java
public static void playRandomSound() {
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()); //seeding random with current time
        int soundRnd = random.nextInt(3);
        switch(soundRnd) 
        {
        case 1:
            String filepath = "Death1.wav";
            soundStuff soundObject = new soundStuff();
            soundObject.playMusic(filepath);
            
        case 2:
            String filepath = "Death2.wav";
            soundStuff soundObject = new soundStuff();
            soundObject.playMusic(filepath);
            
        case 3:
            String filepath = "Death3.wav";
            soundStuff soundObject = new soundStuff();
            soundObject.playMusic(filepath); 
            
        }
    }
```

I get a "soundStuff cannot be resolved to a type" error, which despite searching the internet in general and this site in particular for the better part of the last 30+ minutes, I can't solve. Any and all help is greatly appreciated TIA

Comment: Add the Game.java class here also

Comment: I've added the relevant part of the class, what else do you need?

Comment: *"what else do you need?"* We don't need anything. If *you* want best chance of help.. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). BTW: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: BTW (2): `File soundPath = new File(Location);` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the (badly named - class names begin upper case in Java) `soundStuff` along with your `Game`. Currently it's not being seen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some java trickery from the looks of it. Deleting the project and remaking it from scratch solved the problem. Thanks to everyone for their help.